# String from file not working

Tags: php, string, preg-match, fread

I'm having trouble with a string converted from a file resulting in the same as that string would behave if it was inputted directly:

Here is my test.html file:

```
<html>

<font class="editable">
This is editable section 1
</font>
<br><br><hr><br>
<font class="editable">
This is editable section 2
</font>

</html>
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php

//RETURN ARRAY OF RESULTS FOUND BETWEEN START & END IN STRING
function returnStartEnd($string,$start,$end){ 
     preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '(.*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $string, $m); 
     $out = array(); 

     foreach($m[1] as $key => $value){ 
       $type = explode('::',$value); 
       if(sizeof($type)>1){ 
          if(!is_array($out[$type[0]])) 
             $out[$type[0]] = array(); 
          $out[$type[0]][] = $type[1]; 
       } else { 
          $out[] = $value; 
       } 
     } 
  return $out; 
};


// RETURN FILE CONTENTS AS A STRING
function readFileToVar($file){
  $fh = fopen($file,'r') or die($php_errormsg);
  $html = fread($fh,filesize($file));
  return $html;
  fclose($fh) or die($php_errormsg);
};

$file = 'test.html';
$html = readFileToVar($file);
// OR
//$html = '<html> <font class="editable"> This is editable section 1 </font><br><br><hr><br><font class="editable"> This is editable section 2 </font> </html>';
$go = 'editable">';
$stop = '<';

$arrayOfEditables = returnStartEnd($html,$go,$stop);
echo "<br>Result:<br>";
var_dump($arrayOfEditables);

?>
```

Note the commented out $html. It is the same as what should(?) be returned from the test.html file. When trying to run the function returnStartEnd(), it works as expected on the commented out string, but not on the string created from file, returning an empty array.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? That's **much simpler**.

Comment: One thing to note is that your are calling `fclose($fh)` AFTER you call **return**. `fclose()` is never happening.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a piece of script I found either on stack or php.net. @AlvinWong I've tried file_get_contents several times for this kind of functionality but can never get the string to behave like I would expect. could you please post a working example?

Comment: What? As simple as `$html = file_get_contents($file)`

Comment: @AlvinWong It never works for me. (admittingly I'm a php newbie) It also returns an array of 0 when the string should return an array of 2

Comment: @JMax Thanks, placed it above the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem:

To me it is looking as if the regular expression is having trouble with the multiple lines. That appears to be the difference between the string that you passed in (bypassing the `file_get_contents()`) and the contents of the loaded file.

#### Solution:

Change the value of your regular express to allow for multiple lines:

```
$expression = '/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/') . '/im';
```

This regular expression looks for the starting, and puts all values between that and the end into a character class. Then, at the end, I added the `m` modifier, which puts it into multi-line mode.

According to my tests, both ways, this was what made it work for me:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>

<font class="editable">
This is editable section 1
</font>
<br><br><hr><br>
<font class="editable">
This is editable section 2
</font>

</html>
HTML;

$alternate = '<html><font class="editable">This is editable section 1</font><br><br><hr><br><font class="editable">This is editable section 2</font></html>';

var_dump($html);
$expression = '/' . preg_quote('editable">', '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote('<', '/') . '/im';
var_dump($expression);

preg_match_all($expression, $html, $m);
var_dump($m);

preg_match_all($expression, $alternate, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Comment: Thanks JMax and @AlvinWong. Updated expression and worked. Changed out the readFileToVar() for file_get_contents and it also worked as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for reading a file into a variable as a string.
So:

```
$html = file_get_contents($file);
```

Also, it is always a good idea to use an absolute path (like `dirname(__FILE__)."/file.ext"`) or a relative path prefixed with `./` (like `"./file.ext"`). So you can try changing

```
$file = 'test.html';
```

into

```
$file = './test.html';
```

or even

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/test.html'
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the $file part. However putting `$html = file_get_contents($file);` in there still doesn't work. Even though it returns a string, that string isn't behaving the same as a string where the same contents are manually input.

Comment: @John use `var_dump($html)` to show what's inside it. A probable cause is that there are newline characters (`"\n"`) in your file.

Comment: I know it comes up as a string and appears to work as expected. When I try and put that string into the $arrayOfEditables function, it behaves differently than the commented out $html version of the same string value. I've tried things like htmlspecialchars and htmlentities, to get it to work but have been unsuccessful. returnStartEnd should output an array of 2 on that string value. With both the readFileToVar and your suggestion of simply using file_get_contents instead, it returns an array of 0 which means it is behaving differently and not what I want.